# What is the difference between a volume and persistent volume?

Tags: kubernetes

I've previously used both types, I've also read through the docs at:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/

However it's still not clear what the difference is, both seem to support the same storage types, the only thing that comes to mind is there seems to be a 'provisioning' aspect to persistent volumes.

**What is the practical difference?
Are there advantages / disadvantages between the two - or for what use case would one be better suited to than the other?**

**Is it perhaps just 'synctactic sugar'?**

For example NFS could be mounted as a volume, or a persistent volume. Both require a NFS server, both will have it's data 'persisted' between mounts. What difference would be had in this situation?

Comment: Welcome to the bizarre world of Kubernetes. Wait until they add `ephemeral-volumes`, `temporary-volumes`, `non-existent-volumes`, etc...

Answer (score 45):

Volume decouples the storage from the Container. Its lifecycle is coupled to a pod. It enables safe container restarts and sharing data between containers in a pod.

Persistent Volume decouples the storage from the Pod. Its lifecycle is independent. It enables safe pod restarts and sharing data between pods.

Comment: Yeah - still don't understand

Comment: Practical example, consided pod in aws az - 1a and "volume" created in 1a and attached to the pod. Things are fine. Now the pod crashes and needs to be rescheduled. It can get scheduled to az - 1b but the volume is in 1a and hence wont get attached. If we use a persistent volume instead, k8s will consider the az into pod scheduling and only schedule on 1a. https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/best-practices/multiple-zones/#storage-access-for-zones

Answer (score 16):

A volume exists in the context of a pod, that is, you can't create a volume on its own. A persistent volume on the other hand is a first class object with its own lifecycle, which you can either manage manually or [automatically](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/dynamic-provisioning/).

Comment: A persistent volume can't be used anyway by itself, so the fact that it can exist outside the context of a pod does not seem beneficial? 

The only situation I can think of is a 'persisted' emptyDir - as the data won't be tied to a pod.

Comment: I don't know the historical background why it was considered a good idea to differentiate in terms of terminology between the two of them (that is, I agree it would be cleaner to only have the term volume, maybe I can find that out ;) but a PV clearly allows you separation of concerns: admins take care of the PV itself (either manual or via storage class) and developers use them via claims.

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski The persistent volume can be used by the Pods. That concept is abstracted in Kubernetes by the object called Persistent Volume Claim (PVC).
A Pod can specify a specific claim, which will be responsible for providing the correct Volume to the Pod.

Comment: Let's see if Joe remembers … https://twitter.com/mhausenblas/status/1019919451070849024

Comment: My memory here -- PersistentVolumes (and PersistentVolumeClaims) came later as a way to separate out the lifecycle and permissions around provisioning from the usage of volumes.  Volume (as part of Pod) are a mapping to some sort of storage of various types. This could originally be cloud provider volumes if that were pre-allocated out of band. With the introduction of PVs and PVCs you could have a Volume be a reference to a PVC that is bound to a PV.

Another way to think about it. Pod:Node::PVC:PV -- there is a pairing/scheduling that goes on.

Answer (score 7):

The way I understand it is that the concept of a Persistent Volumes builds on that of a Volume and that the difference is that a Persistent Volume is more decoupled from Pods using it. Or as expressed in the introduction of the documentation page about Persistent Volumes:

> PVs are volume plugins like Volumes, but have a lifecycle independent of any individual pod that uses the PV.

A Volume's lifecycle on the other hand depends on the lifecycle of the Pod using it:

> A Kubernetes volume [...] has an explicit lifetime - the same as the Pod that encloses it.

NFS is not really relevant here. Both Volumes and Persistent Volumes are Kubernetes resources. They provide an **abstraction** of a data storage facility. So for using the cluster, it doesn't matter which concrete operating system resource is behind that abstraction. That's in a way the whole point of Kubernetes.

It might also be relevant here to keep in mind that Kubernetes and its API are still evolving. The Kubernetes developers might sometimes choose to introduce new concepts/resources that differ only subtly from existing ones. I presume one reason for this is to maintain backwards compatibility while still being able to fine tune basic API concepts. Another example for this are Replication Controllers and Replica Sets, which conceptually largely overlap and are therefore redundant to some extent. Although, what's different to the Volume/Persitent Volume matter is that Replication Controllers are explicitly deprecated now.

Comment: What use case can a persistent volume solve that a normal volume can not? Or vice versa. From my understanding so far there are difference indeed but they seem irrelevant?

Answer (score 3):

**Volumes ≠ Persistent Volumes**

Volumes and Persistent Volumes are related, but very different!

**Volumes**:

- appear in Pod specifications
- do not exist as API resources (cannot do `kubectl get volumes`)

**Persistent Volumes**:

- are API resources (can do `kubectl get persistentvolumes`)
- correspond to concrete volumes (e.g. on a SAN, EBS, etc.)
- cannot be associated with a Pod directly
  (they need a Persistent Volume Claim)

Answer (score 0):

They are two different implementations which can provide some similar common functionality (hence a lot of confusion).

Persistent volumes:

- Support storage provisioned via `StorageClass`
- Does not support `emptyDir` volume type (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/75378)

Volumes:

- Are bound to a pod
- Are simpler to define (less Kubernetes resources required)